# How do I prevent '%20' in encoded text from being converted to a space?

Tags: javascript, php, urlencode

I have a web app that accepts and saves plain text input. The relevant JS looks like

```
var newText = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
newText = encodeURIComponent(newText);
var save = new XMLHttpRequest();
save.open('POST', 'write.php', true);
save.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
save.send('u=' + user + '&text=' + newText);
```

and the relevant PHP looks like

```
$savetext = $_POST['text'];
$savetext = rawurldecode($savetext);
```

At this point, if a user originally typed %20 it is saved as a space.

I also tried replacing %20 with + in the JS after `encodeURIComponent` and before sending it, but it didn't seem to help. I still want to preserve actual spaces of course, but in case someone needs to write the actual three character string **%20**, I don't want it to disappear.

Comment: `encodeURIComponent("%20")` will encode it for you

Comment: "if a user originally typed %20 it is saved as a space" — That shouldn't happen. Can you share some code?

Comment: Álvaro I updated the post, sorry

Comment: You don't use `rawurldecode` on the server side. Apache/Nginx does that for you automatically.

Comment: [cannot reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/05vrLqx3/). If user inputs "%20", then it is encoded as "%2520".

Comment: @trincot it's because they're getting "%20" in PHP as the result of automatic decoding, and then manually decoding again on the server side.

Comment: Aha! Thank you miken32!

Comment: Escaping is not the same as encoding. If you encode in e.g. Base64 you need to decode afterwards. Escaping is just a syntax trick.